# data.table error and warnings for finding trigram probability

Tags: r, nlp, data.table, quanteda, trigram

I'm trying the same code as in https://thiloshon.wordpress.com/2018/03/11/build-your-own-word-sentence-prediction-application-part-02/ to do word-level prediction. The input textual data is also in the mentioned link and I use `en_US.news.txt` file as my only input file.

```
library(quanteda)
library(data.table)

#read the .txt file
df=readLines('en_US.news.txt')

#take a sample of the df
sampleHolderNews <- sample(length(df), length(df) * 0.1)
US_News_Sample <- df[sampleHolderNews]

#build the corpus of the data 
corp <- corpus(US_News_Sample)

#Preprocessing

master_Tokens <- tokens(x = tolower(corp),remove_punct = 
TRUE,remove_numbers = TRUE,remove_hyphens = TRUE,remove_symbols = TRUE)
stemed_words <- tokens_wordstem(master_Tokens, language = "english")

#tokenization#
bi_gram <- tokens_ngrams(stemed_words, n = 2)
tri_gram <- tokens_ngrams(stemed_words, n = 3)

uni_DFM <- dfm(stemed_words)
bi_DFM <- dfm(bi_gram)
tri_DFM <- dfm(tri_gram)

uni_DFM <- dfm_trim(uni_DFM, 3)
bi_DFM <- dfm_trim(bi_DFM, 3)
tri_DFM <- dfm_trim(tri_DFM, 3)

sums_U <- colSums(uni_DFM)
sums_B <- colSums(bi_DFM)
sums_T <- colSums(tri_DFM)

# Create data tables with individual words as columns
uni_words <- data.table(word_1 = names(sums_U), count = sums_U)

bi_words <- data.table(
word_1 = sapply(strsplit(names(sums_B), "_", fixed = TRUE), '[[', 1),
word_2 = sapply(strsplit(names(sums_B), "_", fixed = TRUE), '[[', 2),
count = sums_B)

tri_words <- data.table(
word_1 = sapply(strsplit(names(sums_T), "_", fixed = TRUE), '[[', 1),
word_2 = sapply(strsplit(names(sums_T), "_", fixed = TRUE), '[[', 2),
word_3 = sapply(strsplit(names(sums_T), "_", fixed = TRUE), '[[', 3),
count = sums_T)

#indexing#
setkey(uni_words, word_1)
setkey(bi_words, word_1, word_2)
setkey(tri_words, word_1, word_2, word_3)

######## Finding Bi-Gram Probability #################

discount_value <- 0.75
# Finding number of bi-gram words
numOfBiGrams <- nrow(bi_words[.(word_1, word_2)])
# Dividing number of times word 2 occurs as second part of bigram, by total number of bigrams.  
# Finding probability for a word given the number of times it was second word of a bigram
ckn <- bi_words[, .(Prob = ((.N) / numOfBiGrams)), by = word_2]
setkey(ckn, word_2)
# Assigning the probabilities as second word of bigram, to unigrams
uni_words[, Prob := ckn[word_1, Prob]]
uni_words <- uni_words[!is.na(uni_words$Prob)]
# Finding number of times word 1 occurred as word 1 of bi-grams
n1wi <- bi_words[, .(N = .N), by = word_1]
setkey(n1wi, word_1)
# Assigning total times word 1 occured to bigram cn1
bi_words[, Cn1 := uni_words[word_1, count]]
# Kneser Kney Algorithm
bi_words[, Prob := ((count - discount_value) / Cn1 + discount_value / Cn1 * 
n1wi[word_1, N] * uni_words[word_2, Prob])]

######## End of Finding Bi-Gram Probability #################

######## Finding Tri-Gram Probability #################

# Finding count of word1-word2 combination in bigram 
tri_words[, Cn2 := bi_words[.(word_1, word_2), .N]]
n1w12 <- tri_words[, .N, by = .(word_1, word_2)]
setkey(n1w12, word_1, word_2)

# Kneser Kney Algorithm
tri_words[, Prob := ((count - discount_value) / Cn2 + discount_value / Cn2 * 
n1w12[.(word_1, word_2), .N] * bi_words[.(word_1, word_2), Prob])]
```

Here I get the following error for Kneser algorithm for trigrams:

```
 Error in `[.data.table`(tri_words, , `:=`(Prob, ((count - discount_value)/Cn2 +  : 
 Supplied 13867 items to be assigned to 3932 items of column 'Prob'. If you wish to 'recycle' 
 the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
 In addition: Warning messages:
 1: In discount_value/Cn2 * n1w12[list(word_1, word_2), .N] * bi_words[list(word_1,  :
 longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
 2: In (count - discount_value)/Cn2 + discount_value/Cn2 * n1w12[list(word_1,  :
 longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I could find some similar questions related to data table error but I can't understand how should I solve this error in the code.

Comment: Can you please include a fully reproducible example that does not involve reading a long external blog post? I strongly recommend using `reprex::reprex(venue = "so")` for this.

Comment: @KenBenoit just edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your attempt to multiply the quantities in the last line.  This expression:

```
(count - discount_value) / Cn2 + discount_value / Cn2
```

is length 20, like `tri_words`.  But the next expression

```
n1w12[.(word_1, word_2), .N]
```

is length 19.  Then the last part,

```
bi_words[.(word_1, word_2), Prob])
```

is length 155 (and contains a lot of NAs).

The error messages are saying that the shorter item cannot be recycled into the longer item because the longer item's length is not a multiple of the length of the shorter item.  To fix this, you need to implement this algorithm more carefully.